# How to load codemirror js editor into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, codemirror

I want to load codemirror js editor into an iframe to avoid styles overriding. I read the document https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config but it is not clear. Here is what i am tried.

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="code"></iframe>
```

**Js**

```
  var codemirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document.body, {
                    mode: "javascript",
                    theme: "monokai"
  });
```

How can I load codemirror js editor into an iframe?

Comment: is code the initialization inside a load event handler? Where is codemirror.js? What about stylesheet, is it inside iframe? `is not working` is not a proper problem statement

Comment: @charlietfl  
codemirror.js and stylesheets are included in the `parent` document.

Comment: The stylesheet will need to be appended inside iframe and you need to make sure iframe has loaded before trying to manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

Place below code in your html markup.

```
<iframe src="https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config"></iframe>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I believe my question is not clear for you. I want to use codemirror js editor in my web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have CodeMirror in an iframe, you will need two different html files. See a very simple example below. Please be a little bit more specific for  further requirements.

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/doc/docs.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src=http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js></script>
    <script src=http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js></script>
    <style type=text/css>
        .CodeMirror {float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>  
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <textarea id=content name="content"></textarea>
  </div>
    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('content'), {
        mode: 'application/x-httpd-php',
        lineNumbers: true
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```